# How to print part of header and string in another file in Perl

Tags: perl, header, output

I am starting to work in Perl. I have a file called `file_IN.txt` which contains the following lines:

```
SITE     1   
         /def="CODE:X22"      
         /pattern="BBAACCLLDDCC"     
SITE     2  
         /def="CODE:X33".  
         /pattern="MMKKNNJJXXVV"
```

I want to print all "patterns" (i.e.  BBAACCLLDDCC) in another file called `file_OUT.txt`, taking into consideration the "def" part (i.e. X22) as a header:

Example outputs:

```
>X22  
BBAACCLLDDCC.  
>X33        
MMKKNNJJXXVV
```

I tried the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;

if(!open(MY_HANDLE, "file_IN.txt")){
    die "Cannot open the file";
}
@content = <MY_HANDLE>;
close(MY_HANDLE);

if(!open(WRITE_HANDLE, ">>file_OUT.txt")){
    die "Cannot open the file";
}
foreach $row (@content){
    if ($row =~ /def="([A-Z\/:A-Z]+)"/g){
    $def = $1
    }
    if ($row =~ /pattern="([A-Z\s]+)"/){
    $seqs = $1;
    }
}
print(WRITE_HANDLE $seqs);
```

The problems I encountered with this code are:

1. It only prints the last pattern into `file_OUT.txt`
2. I don't know how to print the header and the pattern consecutively for each site.

Comment: I guess the dots don't belong to the input nor output.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the header in a variable, print it when you encounter the pattern:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $def;
while (<>) {
    $def = $1 if m{/def="CODE:(.*?)"};
    print ">$def\n$1\n" if m{/pattern="(.*?)"};
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried but I am still not able to implement the initial code and print headers in the output file. Any hint?

Comment: Instead of the `<>` put your file handle.

Comment: Use `<$filehandle>` instead of `<>` and `print {$filehandle_out}` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer, but while editing some minor details in the posted script

```
use strict;
use warnings;

if(!open(MY_HANDLE, "file_IN.txt")){
    die "Cannot open the file";
}
my @content = <MY_HANDLE>;
close(MY_HANDLE);

if(!open(WRITE_HANDLE, ">>file_OUT.txt")){
    die "Cannot open the file";
}

foreach my $row (@content){
  chomp($row);
  if ($row =~ /def="[A-Z]*\:([A-Z|0-9]+)"/g){
    print (WRITE_HANDLE ">".$1."\n");
  }
  if ($row =~ /pattern="([A-Z\s]+)"/){
    print (WRITE_HANDLE $1."\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now file_OUT.txt contains both patterns but headers are not printed. Maybe something in regex ($row =~ /def="[A-Z]\:([A-Z|0-9]+)"/)?